# How to handle with nested forms in Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, spring, spring-mvc

I have a model A with a one-to-many relation with B and C.
I want to, inside A's create form display one table containing all Bs and another containing all Cs while being able to create new Bs and Cs to the new A.

In rails this could be easily handled by https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form Is there anything similar on Spring?

What would be the best way to deal with this problem?

I'm using Spring 3 with JSP template engine.

Comment: What templating engine you using?  JSP/Thymeleaf/Velocity, based on that answer would vary. Please ensure you update it in the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm using JSP as template engine